# Javascript - variable previous business day

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a drop down list that will automatically enter dates into text fields.

The option "LBD" currently returns yesterday's date, however, I'd like it to return the date of the last business day. So that if today is Monday, it would return Friday's date, if today is Tuesday it would return Monday's date. So on and so forth.

This is what I've got so far:

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datetype option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#datepickstart").val();
    return $(this).val() == $("#datepickend").val();
}).attr('selected', true);
    var d = new Date();
var yesterday = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getDate() - 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
var today = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
var fdm = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/01/' + d.getFullYear();
var fdy = '01/01/' + new Date().getFullYear();
$("#datetype").on("change", function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
    if (selectedVal == 'LBD') {
        $("#datepickstart").val((yesterday));
        $("#datepickend").val((yesterday));
    }
    if (selectedVal == 'MtD') {
        $("#datepickstart").val(fdm);
        $("#datepickend").val(today);
    }
    if (selectedVal == 'YtD') {
        $("#datepickstart").val(fdy);
        $("#datepickend").val(today);
    }
});
})
</script>
```

html:

```
<select id="datetype" name="datetype"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="LBD">LBD</option> 
<option value="MtD">MtD</option> 
<option value="YtD">YtD</option> 
</select>

<input type="text" id="datepickstart" name="datepickstart" value="">
<input type="text" id="datepickend" name="datepickend" value="">
```

Comment: The code is simple `while (!isBusinessDay(date)) { date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1) }`, the hard part is writing the `isBusinessDay` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your expected result, calculate day and reduce the days to get previous business day.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datetype option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#datepickstart").val();
    return $(this).val() == $("#datepickend").val();
  }).attr('selected', true);

  var d = new Date();
  var bd = d.getDay();
  if (bd < 2) {
    if (bd == 0) {
      bd = 2;
    } else {
      bd = 3;
    }
  } else {
    bd = 1;
  }
  var today = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
  var lbd = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getDate() - bd) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
  var fdm = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/01/' + d.getFullYear();

  var fdy = '01/01/' + new Date().getFullYear();

  $("#datetype").on("change", function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
    if (selectedVal == 'LBD') {
      $("#datepickstart").val(lbd);
      $("#datepickend").val(today);
    }
    if (selectedVal == 'MtD') {
      $("#datepickstart").val(fdm);
      $("#datepickend").val(today);
    }
    if (selectedVal == 'YtD') {
      $("#datepickstart").val(fdy);
      $("#datepickend").val(today);
    }

  });
});
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wWgQYE

LBD calculation part

```
  var bd = d.getDay();// get day from today's date which be between 0-6 (0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday
  if (bd < 2) {
    if (bd == 0) {
      bd = 2;
    } else {
      bd = 3;
    }
  } else {
    bd = 1;
  }
 //variable lbd will get the last business day by reducing the calculated lbd from today's date
  var lbd = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getDate() - bd) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 15):

getDay() function is the key for your problem. I used @zzzzBov snippet for iterator. Below is my solution

```
step1:
   function isBusinessDay(date){
    var day = date.getDay();
    if(day == 0 || day == 6  ){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }


 step2:
    var date = new Date();
    while (!isBusinessDay(date)) { date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1) }

    console.log(date);//date always between monday to friday
```

Hope this solves your problem. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the javascript `getDay()` method to return you an integer representing the day of the week:

> The value returned by getDay() is an integer corresponding to the day of the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

[See docs for getDay() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

So you could write a method that returns false if getDay() returns 0 (Sunday) or 6 (Saturday).

Answer (score 1):

```
function isBusinessDay(theDate){
  theDay = theDate.getDay(); // Get day returns 0-6, respectively Sunday - Saturday
  if(theDay == 0 || theDay == 6){
     return false;
  } else {
     return true;
  }
}
```

Use with zzzzBov's `while (!isBusinessDay(date)) { date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1) }`

A more concise way to write it :

```
function isBusinessDay(theDate){
  theDay = theDate.getDay(); // Get day returns 0-6, respectively Sunday - Saturday
  if(theDay == 0 || theDay == 6) return false;
  return true;
}
```